# How does MGF of Pareto distribution of first kind exist for non-positive values of t?

Tags: moment-generating-function, pareto-distribution

I have reached upto the stage shown in the attached picture. The r.v. X is always positive and its power $\beta+1$ is also always positive. Therefore, how can it be said that MGF exists for t <= 0? For using the definition of Gamma function, doesn't the power of x, when taken to the numerator, be greater than -1?[image]

Comment: Hello, please write out all formulas in the pic. It's a house rule on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $X$ is a random variable such that $P(X\ge 0) =1$, then the mgf always exists for $t\le 0$. See:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
   M_X(t)= \E e^{t X} = \E e^{-|t| |X|} \quad\text{so the argument of $\exp$ is never positive} \\
\le 1
$$
So it always exists for $t \le 0$. Pareto is just a special case of that.